# Why is my menu bar not shrinking correctly in wordpress when it is shrinking as it should in an ordinary html file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

The menu bar i am currently using is not shrinking as it should when implemented in wordpress but shrinks as it should when i am just testing in an ordinary .html file.

I have tried changing the value for the javascript values and it doesn't seem to affect anything when changed in wordpress.

I expect the navbar element to shrink when scrolling more than 80px down on site. But instead it enlarges when scrolling more than 80px...

```js
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "10px 10px";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "25px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "30px 10px";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "35px";
  }
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f6f5f2 !important;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
#navbar {
  box-shadow:1px 3px 1px #B6B6B6;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#navbar #logo {
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
#navbar a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#navbar a.active {
  color: #A9A9A9;
}
#navbar-right {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 80px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  #navbar {
    padding: 20px 10px !important;
  }
  #navbar a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  #navbar-right {
    float: none;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<div id="navbar"><a id="logo" href="http://enkien.dk">Koebenhavner</a>
<div id="navbar-right"><a class="active" href="http://enkien.dk">HOME</a>
<a href="http://enkien.dk/contact">CONTACT</a>
<a href="http://enkien.dk/about">ABOUT</a></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please do some basic debugging and add `console.log(document.body.scrollTop);` to your scroll handler, then check the console. It's also possible that the wordpress theme is interfering?

Comment: It returns the value 0 in the console, i am pretty new to this and not aware of what this means. Could you maybe explain further?

Comment: Is the site online so I can take a look?

Comment: yes - site is online. http://enkien.dk

Comment: If you look at the source you'll find `scrollFunction` at the very bottom, it currently sets the padding to `15px 15px` if you scroll down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the link in your html snippet and checked out your scroll function.

Try using `window.scrollY` instead of `document.body.scrollTop`. Maybe Wordpress is inserting some styles and/or html containers in the body which is interfering with size and overflow behavior of the body.

```js
function scrollFunction() {
  if (window.scrollY > 80) { // <-- Updated this line
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "10px 10px";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "25px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "30px 10px";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "35px";
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.